# Is it possible to write all client information to only one agconnect-services.json file?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification

I want to use Push Kit and I use product flavors in my project.  There are 4 different build variants and package names in my project.

[image]

**Package Names:**

```
variant: blueDebug           -  package_name: com.omfaer.pflavors.blue.debug
variant: blueRelease         -  package_name: com.omfaer.pflavors.blue
variant: developmentDebug    -  package_name: com.omfaer.pflavors.debug
variant: developmentRelease  -  package_name: com.omfaer.pflavors
```

I have added agconnect-services.json to different directories. It works this way.

[image]

**My Question:**

Is it possible to write all client information to only one agconnect-services.json file. Can't I write client information as a array in json file?

For example, I tried this by editing the json file for two different debug variants as below and it doesn't work.

```json
{
    "agcgw":{
        "websocketbackurl":"connect-ws-dre.hispace.dbankcloud.cn",
        "backurl":"connect-dre.dbankcloud.cn",
        "websocketurl":"connect-ws-dre.hispace.dbankcloud.com",
        "url":"connect-dre.hispace.hicloud.com"
    },
    "client":[
        {
            "appType":"1",
            "cp_id":"****************",
            "product_id":"************",
            "client_id":"************",
            "client_secret":"********************",
            "project_id":"******************",
            "app_id":"123456789", 
            "api_key":"********************************************",
            "package_name":"com.omfaer.pflavors.debug"
        },
        {
            "appType":"1",
            "cp_id":"****************",
            "product_id":"************",
            "client_id":"************",
            "client_secret":"********************",
            "project_id":"******************",
            "app_id":"987654321",
            "api_key":"********************************************",
            "package_name":"com.omfaer.pflavors.blue.debug"
        }
    ],

    ...
}
```

---

I've looked at the Huawei Push Kit documentation and SDK integration documentation.
I have looked at the links below. I've also reviewed the sample codes.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-config-flavor

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/service-introduction-0000001050040060

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Examples/client-sample-code-0000001051066000

**app/build.gradle**

```
android {
    ...

    signingConfigs {
        release{
            storeFile file('keystore.jks')
            keyAlias '***'
            keyPassword '********'
            storePassword '********'
            v1SigningEnabled true
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix = '.debug'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        development {
            minSdkVersion 19
            resConfigs("en", "xhdpi")
            dimension "default"
        }
        blue {
            applicationIdSuffix = '.blue'
            dimension "default"
        }
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Is there a solution for this? Can you help with this?

Comment: Is it possible to write all client information to only one agconnect-services.json file?---As relevant team confirmed,We don't support that. :(

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. There is no .json file for .blue.debug in the question. What's the best way to do this? Should I create the "blue" directory under the "debug" directory or the "debug" directory under the "blue" directory? Do you have any other suggestions? @shirley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no .json file for .blue.debug in the question. What's the best way to do this? Should I create the "blue" directory under the "debug" directory or the "debug" directory under the "blue" directory? Do you have any other suggestions?

You need to create a .blue.debug project on AGC, and download the corresponding JSON file, then create a flavor in the project,The folder can be named randomly,as long as the package name corresponding to the flavor is .blue.debug. Then put the JSON file in this folder is fine.